# C#: How do you access an integer in the main UI thread from another thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, integer

How do you access an integer (increment nCount++) in the main form from the method of an asynchronous callback function?

I know that with methods you have to check if invoke is required, then call begininvoke for the intended method as a delegate, as to avoid an illegal threading operation, but how an you perform a simple operation such as nCount++ from another thread?

Answer (score 4):

```
Interlocked.Increment(ref variable);
```

Comment: int result = Interlocked.Increment(ref variable);
to read:
int result = Interlocked.Read(ref variable);
Good answer though. Upvote.

Comment: @Jon there is no Interlocked.Read(ref int), so your second example won't compile.